# Usar Sessions no wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou a usar o wordpress para criar a minha aplicação. Nesta aplicação estou a usar o login do wordpress e a tentar usar Sessions.

As páginas que estou a criar novas no wordpress estou a criar no diretório onde temos o wp-login.php.

Para usar as sessions estou a colocar este código dentro do functions.php do tema, mas estou a criar as páginas fora do diretório do tema como expliquei acima:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['usuarioId'] = $user_ID;;
$_SESSION['usuarioNome'] = $user_identity;
$_SESSION['email'] = $user_email;
$_SESSION['login'] = $user_login;
$_SESSION['image'];
function register_my_session(){
    if(! session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
}
```

Quando faço login, faço o reencaminhamento logo para uma página que criei, como o nome home.php, que inicio essa página com o seguinte código:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['usuarioId'];
$_SESSION['usuarioNome'];
$_SESSION['email'];
$_SESSION['login'];

if(!isset($_SESSION['usuarioId']) || !isset($_SESSION['usuarioNome']) || !isset($_SESSION['email'])){
header('Location: https://gestao.centropadreangelo.pt/login');
exit;
}
```

Agora quando faço login e faz o redireccionamento para a página home.php, as sessions ficam vazias. Mas se forçar o acesso à página wp-admin e depois voltar aceder à página home.php, já retorna os valores corretos nas sessions.

Pretendo que logo ao fazer o redireccionamento do login para o home.php retorne logo os valores nas sessions.

Podem ajudar a resolver este problema?

Answer (score -3):

Você pode usar a função: "is_user_logged_in()" para validar se o usuário estado logado, a função "wp_get_current_user()" pode retornar os valores necessários para seu controle.

Refs:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/